# IBM Worklight 7.0 with Sencha Touch How to optimize Application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, senchatouch-2.4

I am Working on an IBM  Worklight 7.0 Hybrid mobile application with Sencha touch 2.4 . It initially takes too much time to load. The network load for the application shows an idle time for about 10 sec when monitored using the chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce application load time you can do several things:

1. Do not connect to the server on application launch is it is not required
2. Use [minification and concatenation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_build_settings.html) to reduce network load by making the app 'smaller'
3. Make sure you are not adding to your project stuff that you're not actually using

Answer (score 1):

The initial delay to load might be owing to the sizeable app.css that has to be parsed and rendered (about 1.2 MB).

The same query and solution is mentioned in the Sencha blog [here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/4-tricks-for-smaller-css-in-touch-22/).

Answer (score 0):

To add to @IdanAdar Answer:

Don't know if you are using [Sencha CMD](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/) or not but it doesn't sound like you are.

In the Terminal or equivalent in Windows:

```
$ cd to/your/project/directory

$ sencha app build build         # runs a build, warns about errors

$ sencha app build testing       # combines js files but not uglified

$ sencha app build production    # minifies project
```

This should create a `build` folder in your project with a deployable versions of each kind of build if you have run the command.

MyProject/build/production/MyApp

**EDIT:**

In your app.js you have a

Ext.application({

```
name: 'MyApp',

requires: [
    // Are you loading everything here?
    // If you have framework classes that are not 
    // in your initial views you could move them
    // to a subview in.. requires: ['Ext.field.CheckBox','Ext.etc']
],

models: [...],

stores: [...],

    // Are you loading all of your views here?
    // If you can get away with loading nested views try that.

views: [
    'Main'
],

controllers: [...],

icon: {...},

isIconPrecomposed: true,

startupImage: {...},

launch: function() {

    Ext.create('IntakEase.view.Main', {fullscreen: true});
}
```

There's many other possible things.

Are you loading any external Classes?

Comment: Yes We are using Sencha CMD. and We use $ sencha app build --destination ../ourpath/abcd package

Comment: Ok. it sounds like the first answer you got is the route to take. I'll edit my answer to touch on some of the things I would look at. These comment boxes are terrible to write in.